# Proving/Disproving injectivity with $f(x,y,z) = (x+z, y-2z, -x-y+z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this is really simple, but it's aggravating the hell out of me.

Say we have $(a,b,c),(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $f(a,b,c) = f(x,y,z)$.

This means that:
\begin{align}a+c &= x+z \\
b-2c &= y-2z\\
-a-b+c &= -x-y+z\end{align}

I can't find solutions to these, which tells me its probably injective. To make sure, I'd like to find a value to show that it's not, but I don't have the intuition. What should I be doing in these cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function is linear so $f(a,b,c)=f(x,y,z)$ iff $f(a-x,b-y,c-z)=0$.

So to prove that $f$ is injective it is sufficient to prove thta $f(x,y,z)=0 \Rightarrow (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ ( the same method can be used for any linear function).

So you only have to solve the system:
\begin{align}
&x+z=0\\
&y-2z=0\\
&-x-y+z=0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's actually quite interesting, I've never looked at it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The linear map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given by the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
Its determinant is $0$. Hence the kernel is non trivial and the map is not injective.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you mind doing this without using matrices/determinants, but just linear systems? It's more of a conceptual problem for me; I don't know what to do after I reach the point where I can't show that a = x, b = y, c = z. How can I determine that it's injective when I can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

To show it is not injective, you have to show ONE of the following:

- that there is a vector in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ for which there is no vector that maps to it.
- that the dimension of the range is less than the dimension of the domain.  You can do this by noting that the mapping is from $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ to $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ but the dimension of the null space is greater than zero.

and there are a bunch of equivalent ways of showing it.  The bottom line is that the natural way to show all this is to formulate the problem as a set of linear equations, with a matrix.  So, don't fight that.  Embrace it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'm confused, but I thought that proving that there's an unmapple vector disproves surjectivity, and to disprove injectivity, you have to show that there's an vector which is mapped by more than vector, no?

Comment: @user494405 If you show that the kernel is nontrivial, then you have a whole bunch of vectors that all get mapped to zero.